# How to draw a smooth curve through given points (2D) within a certain deviation?

Tags: curves, interpolation, piecewise-continuity

There are algorithms to draw smooth curve through given points but I want the curve between any two points to always be within a certain distance (i.e. the deviation I mentioned in the title) from the straight line connecting those two points. So far I have used curves of type $$ax^2+by^2+cx+dy+gxy+h=0$$for each consecutive pair of points and equated second derivatives (i.e. derivative of gradients) on both side of a point. Still I have found no guarantee of maintaining that deviation. Can anyone please help? [Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LayWs.jpg) for explaining the thing but the drawing is a bit rough.

Comment: Could you to be more precise? Perhaps including a small example...

Comment: @Cesareo included

Comment: In geometric software like Autocad choose an arbitrarily small fillet radius at each given point.

Comment: @Narasimham But I want the algorithm

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Comment: If 3 points and fillet radius are given we can find the arc coordinates.

Comment: @Narasimham yah but we have more than three points and simply adding curve sections will not give smooth curve for arbitrary fillet radius. I have tried. The problem is to find that particular set of fillet radius which will make the curve smooth. And by smooth I mean second derivative's equality (see question) at each point.

Comment: Then I would repeat Cesareo. The splines minimize bending, hence are nearest to the polygonal line for the full line.